# No layout and no results on magento results page

Tags: magento, search, full-text-search, magento-1.7

I get no Layout and no results on the result page in magento.

Layout catalogsearch.xml looks like this :

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
<label>Quick Search Form</label>
<update handle="page_two_columns_left" />
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
        </block>
        <action method="setListOrders"/>
        <action method="setListModes"/>
        <action method="setListCollection"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Can anyone help ?

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below handler and check it. No need to update any handle for this

```
update handle="page_two_columns_left"
```

If it does not work then try to remove `catalogsearch.xml` from that theme.

Comment: Removing the line didn't help! I removed the file and it worked great :D thank you very very much. 
i have one question : after removing the file, what Layout is assigned for the search result ??

Comment: Magento use call back functionality for that. If magento can not find that xml into current theme. then it will find from base theme.

Comment: okay. So i copied now the content of (Catalogsearch.xml in Base) to (Catalogsearch.xml in my template). is this a better and safer way to assign the template ?

Comment: yes..if want to any customization like change layout, add block etc.